# When text comes in other text moves

Tags: jquery, html, css

A logo comes when you scroll down, but the text beside that logo moves when it fade in. Is there an other way to fix it than "position: absolute;" ?
So the text have to stay where it is in the beginning.

JS:

```js
$('.menu').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.menu').addClass('cloned').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0').css('margin-top', '0').css('z-index', '500').removeClass('original').hide();

scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);


function stickIt() {

  var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
  orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {

    orgElement = $('.original');
    coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
    leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;
    widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');
    $('.cloned').css('left', leftOrgElement + 'px').css('top', 0).css('width', widthOrgElement).show();
    $('.original').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  } else {
    $('.cloned').hide();
    $('.original').css('visibility', 'visible');
  }
}



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.logo').hide();
});
$(document).scroll(function(e) {
  if (document.body.scrollTop >= 76) {
    $('.logo').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.logo').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
body,
head {
  padding: 0px auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
}
#head {
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #3279B8;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  font-family: Raleway-Regular;
  font-size: 23px;
}
.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
}
.menu a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}
.menu a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
}
.link {
  margin-left: 35%;
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  }

Fonts:(I know they fucked up...)

@font-face {
  font-family: Kaushan Script;
  src: url(font/KaushanScript.otf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Quicksand-Regular;
  src: url(font/Quicksand-Regula
    r.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Quicksand-Bold;
  src: url(font/Quicksand-Bold.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Quicksand-Light;
  src: url(font/Quicksand-Light.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Raleway-Regular;
  src: url(font/Raleway-Regular.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Raleway-ExtraLight;
  src: url(font/Raleway-ExtraLight.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Raleway-Light;
  src: url(font/Raleway-Light.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Raleway-Medium;
  src: url(font/Raleway-Medium.ttf);
}
#font1 {
  font-family: Kaushan Script;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #3279B8;
}
#font1-1 {
  font-family: Kaushan Script;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#font2 {
  font-family: Quicksand-Bold;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  color: #A3A3A3;
}
#font2-2 {
  font-family: Quicksand-Bold;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  color: #A3A3A3;
}
#font3 {
  font-family: Quicksand-Light;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #3F3F3F;
}
#font4 {
  font-family: Raleway-ExtraLight;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #3F3F3F;
}
#Bla {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="background-color: white;">

  <div class="w3-container w3-xlarge" id="head">
    <h id="font1">Loftus</h>
    <h id="font2">DENTAL</h>

    <div id="Bla">
      <h id="font3">Bla</h>
      <h id="font4">&</h>
      <h id="font3">bla</h>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="nav">
      <h class="logo">
        <h id="font1-1">Loftus</h>
        <h id="font2-2">DENTAL</h>
      </h>
      <h class="link">
        <li> <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Photo's</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </h>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color: white;">
    Hi
    <br>
    Hi
    <br>
    Hi
    <br>
    Hi
    <br>
     Hi
    <br>
    Hi
    <br>
    Hi
    <br>
    Hi
    <br>
     Hi
    <br>
    Hi
    <br>
    Hi
    <br>
    Hi
    <br>
     Hi
    <br>
    Hi
    <br>
    Hi
    <br>
    Hi
    <br>
     Hi
    <br>
    Hi
    <br>
    Hi
    <br>
    Hi
    <br>
     
  </div>

  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

</body>
```

Comment: There's really no `<h>` tag...

Comment: Do you mean to say you don't want the text to move?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes!

Comment: @PraveenKumar Oké! Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend *strongly* against relying on a w3schools javascript library that is loaded directly from w3schools!  If you want to use that library, save it to your local server and load it from your own server.

Comment: @JornVeltrop Let me know if it works... `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to keep the logo out of the flow by adding `position: absolute` or something to make it keep its position out, without disturbing the text. In smaller devices obviously, you cannot have it, as it will mess up the layout by overlapping.

This is what I added in the CSS:

```
.logo {
  position: absolute;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .logo {
    position: static;
  }
}
```

See the solution I have:

```js
$('.menu').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.menu').addClass('cloned').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0').css('margin-top', '0').css('z-index', '500').removeClass('original').hide();

scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);


function stickIt() {

  var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
  orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {

    orgElement = $('.original');
    coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
    leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;
    widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');
    $('.cloned').css('left', leftOrgElement + 'px').css('top', 0).css('width', widthOrgElement).show();
    $('.original').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  } else {
    $('.cloned').hide();
    $('.original').css('visibility', 'visible');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.logo').hide();
});
$(document).scroll(function(e) {
  if (document.body.scrollTop >= 76) {
    $('.logo').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.logo').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
body,
head {
  padding: 0px auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
}
#head {
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #3279B8;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  font-family: Raleway-Regular;
  font-size: 23px;
}
.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
}
.menu a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}
.menu a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
}
.link {
  margin-left: 35%;
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  }

Fonts:(I know they fucked up...)

@font-face {
  font-family: Kaushan Script;
  src: url(font/KaushanScript.otf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Quicksand-Regular;
  src: url(font/Quicksand-Regula
    r.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Quicksand-Bold;
  src: url(font/Quicksand-Bold.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Quicksand-Light;
  src: url(font/Quicksand-Light.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Raleway-Regular;
  src: url(font/Raleway-Regular.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Raleway-ExtraLight;
  src: url(font/Raleway-ExtraLight.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Raleway-Light;
  src: url(font/Raleway-Light.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Raleway-Medium;
  src: url(font/Raleway-Medium.ttf);
}
#font1 {
  font-family: Kaushan Script;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #3279B8;
}
#font1-1 {
  font-family: Kaushan Script;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#font2 {
  font-family: Quicksand-Bold;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  color: #A3A3A3;
}
#font2-2 {
  font-family: Quicksand-Bold;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  color: #A3A3A3;
}
#font3 {
  font-family: Quicksand-Light;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #3F3F3F;
}
#font4 {
  font-family: Raleway-ExtraLight;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #3F3F3F;
}
#Bla {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.logo {
  position: absolute;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .logo {
    position: static;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="w3-container w3-xlarge" id="head">
  <h id="font1">Loftus</h>
  <h id="font2">DENTAL</h>

  <div id="Bla">
    <h id="font3">Bla</h>
    <h id="font4">&</h>
    <h id="font3">bla</h>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <ul class="nav">
    <h class="logo">
      <h id="font1-1">Loftus</h>
      <h id="font2-2">DENTAL</h>
    </h>
    <h class="link">
      <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#">Photo's</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </h>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> **Note:** It is better not to hotlink the CSS from W3Schools.

**Output: http://output.jsbin.com/kaqijohayo**